# Updating One Access Database From Another

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction. This is with regards to Access 2007.

There are two databases. The first one is a complete list of all employees with up to date addresses. The second database is comprised of a specific group of the employees from the first database who will be receiving a letter, but the addresses are not up to date.

How would I go about taking the current and up to date addresses of these employees from the first database and updating the second database?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have two databases with overlapping data? Looks to me like all of it belongs in a single database (and in a single table, in fact).

Answer (score 2):

The logical thing to do would be to link to the employee's table in the first database (DB1) from the second database (DB2) and create a linked table (give it a meaningful name). In older version of MS Access you can do in the File menu: `File -> Get External Data -> Link Tables`

Then you would do a query with a join on DB2's Employee table and the linked table.

```
SELECT foo.f0, foo.f1, foo.f2, bar.f1
FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON foo.f0 = bar.f0;
```

You can then build your mailing list based on this new query instead of the table.

Alternately, you could also update the DB2's employee table based upon the previous query with an Update Query.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest and best solution is using "link table".

how to create link table:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/link-tables-in-an-access-project-by-using-the-link-table-wizard-adp-HP003089371.aspx